# tango app goal achievable in 180 hours

Tags: google-project-tango

I'm about to start my Bachelor's thesis (estimated workload of around **180 programming hours** and 180 hours of actual writing the thesis). As I have zero experience with Google's project Tango, I don't know whether my goal is achievable at all or way too big without me realizing it.

I would like to develop a "blueprint app" that uses Tango to create a blueprint of a scanned area. I.e. I want to go around my apartment with the device in my hand, scan it and afterwards have a file in which I can see all the dimensions of all rooms, see doors (and windows?), but not see things lying around like cloths, books, even shelves, chairs or my guitar.

I believe that this is generally possible with Tango, although I can imagine it to be quiet hard, as soon as I want to include some data but exclude other.

I realize that an answer heavily depends on the person. I have a little more than 3 years of programming experience in Java. And I have developed a small Android app so that I know the fundamentals of lifecycles etc. My last programming project was a simple web shop including a restful Spring backend, and an AngularJS frontend. I use frameworks where possible and so far don't seem to have bigger problems with google's APIs.

So my question is: Am I crazy to even think that's possible or do you (people with knowledge of Tango) think it could be done?

Comment: A floorplan app is reasonable, but make it fully automated is tricky. Segmenting objects from wall is a non-trivial task at all. Tango has an example code project show how to create a floor plan using depth camera. The procedure it uses is to let user point depth to each of the wall in a room and intersect all the lines to generate floor plan.

Comment: Also, project tango g+ page is a much more active place for asking questions like this: https://plus.sandbox.google.com/communities/114537896428695886568

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! I'll have a look at the community as well. The app, you mentioned, you didn't mean [this one](http://www.sensopia.com/english/press/tango.html), but rather [this](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.projecttango.tangomeasureit), right?

Comment: Or did you mean [this](https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java/tree/master/java_floor_plan_example) example?

Comment: Measure it and sensopia's app are not open sourced. I mean the floor plan sample code:

Comment: https://github.com/googlesamples/tango-examples-java/tree/master/java_floor_plan_example